# Fill web-form using information in another web form - Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

Currently at my company, we are using a CRM to manage invoicing, sales orders, etc. We are also shipping a lot of items. So what I am trying to do is get the information from one web form (the invoice) to fill in the other web form (shipping web application) so there is less room for error when shipping. I would like it to just copy over the basic information like to and from address and PO#.

I found some information on it sending pre-inputted information using VB, but I would like it to grab what is in an ID of a form, since that will constantly be different.

Comment: You can automate IE to do this type of task, but your question is a little too broad to be able to provide useful answers. Your question is tagged VBA did you mean VB.NET ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I think you are correct. I think it is VB.NET
I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKB0K3F1enU but just want it to be dynamic and grab the content that's currently in one form and bring it to another.

Comment: It's not going to know what you want - you have to tell it via your code.  If that's outside of your comfort zone with VB then you'd need to find a contractor to code it for you.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It seems pretty basic, thought it would be a simple questions using the form ID's. Thanks for all of your help, though.

Comment: It's not super complex, but you have to know what you're doing or be willing to do some research: there's no built-in "copy form X content to form Y" capability.